# adding fields in ELK

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm new to ELK, I've installed ELK 5.0 which is up and running. I've figured out for smooth daily activities, a lot of fine tuning is required and I'm uable to figure it out.

I'm using ELK with rsyslog, instead of agents like filebeat. I've enable rsyslog on clients and server, on server rsyslog receives logs and forward to logstash.

Below are the sample message logs which I can see on Kibana

> {"@timestamp":"2017-02-01T05:41:03+04:00","@version":"1","message":"
>   root : unable to resolve host
>   juju-machine-4-lxc-3","sysloghost":"juju-machine-4-lxc-3","severity":"alert","facility":"authpriv","programname":"sudo","procid":"-"}
>
> {"@timestamp":"2017-02-01T05:40:23+04:00","@version":"1","message":"
>   warning: native_choose_node: 2 nodes with equal score (INFINITY) for
>   running res_mysql_vip resources. Chose
>   juju-machine-2-lxc-0.","sysloghost":"juju-machine-2-lxc 0",
>   "severity":"warning","facility":"daemon","programname":"pengine","procid":"18468"}

I would like to add fields which can display minimum information like hostname and ip of logsource, severity label and level. Currently I can see only severity label and in place of host I can only see ip of rsyslog for all logs; whereas it should display actual log source ip.

Below is my configuration of logstash

```
[root@localhost~]# more /etc/logstash/conf.d/10-syslog.conf
# This input block will listen on port 10514 for logs to come in.
# host should be an IP on the Logstash server.
# type => "rsyslog" is an optional identifier to help identify messaging streams in the pipeline.
input {
  syslog {
    port => 10514
    type => rsyslog
  }
}
# This is an empty filter block.  You can later add other filters here to further process
# your log lines
filter {
  if "affinity_hint subset empty" in [message]{drop{}}
}
# Output Section, filtering out rsyslog type and send to elasticsearch
output {
  if [type] == "rsyslog" {
     elasticsearch {
        hosts=> ["localhost:9200"]
        }
```

and below is my json template

```
[root@localhost ~]# more /etc/rsyslog.d/01-json-template.conf
template(name="json-template"
  type="list") {
   constant(value="{")
   constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")  property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value="\",\"@version\":\"1")
    constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg" format="json")
    constant(value="\",\"sysloghost\":\"")  property(name="hostname")
    constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")    property(name="syslogseverity-text")
    constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")    property(name="syslogfacility-text")
    constant(value="\",\"programname\":\"") property(name="programname")
    constant(value="\",\"procid\":\"")      property(name="procid")
    constant(value="\"}\n")
}
```

Kindly help me out..

Comment: What's the *ip* and *severity level* in the log message you provided?

Comment: always shows ip of the rsyslog server, instead of showing ip of original log source. severity level is always 0

Comment: I can see **sysloghost, severity and facility** from your kibana output.

**"sysloghost":"juju-machine-4-lxc-3","severity":"alert","facility":"authpriv"**

**"sysloghost":"juju-machine-2-lxc 0","severity":"warning","facility":"daemon"**

Are these logs belong to rsyslog server itself? If they do, have you verified that logs from clients are really coming to rsyslog server?

By the way, your logstash config has a filter rule that drops messages containing **affinity_hint subset empty**